# blogspot.com: how can i display all posts at once?

Tags: blogspot

I'm reading some blogs on blogspot.com and I was wondering:
is it possible to change a blog's URL that it will display ALL posts?
I mean that it will show all blog entries without having to click "older posts" over + over again.

Comment: This kills number of pageviews and indirectly earnings, So lesser the number of posts displayed on one page larger the number of pageviews and earning probability.

Comment: She is READING public blogs, wants to read with less clicks probably.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Consider this blog:

http://rehmansaad.blogspot.com/

When you hover over the Older Posts link, you get this link:

http://rehmansaad.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2015-04-13T02:46:00-04:00&max-results=20

And as you see, it says max-results=20, and currently you're seeing 20 posts per page, so being the smart guy that you are, you look at all the labels, and count the number of posts there are in every year, and total them. Let's say they are 213. Then you manually this url:

http://rehmansaad.blogspot.com/search?max-results=213

But when you goto that link, you see that only 55 posts are displayed, and there's still a Older Posts button. That's because Blogger at one time doesn't serve pages larger than 1 MB, in case of the said blog 55 posts made 1 MB. So you can click on the Older Posts link, and see the next 55 posts. Hence in about 4 pages (4 MB) you can see the entire blog.

This is as close as you get to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't show all posts.

You can select to show N number of posts or M days of postings on each page. A limit of 500 posts per page is enforced however.

These options are available on the Settings->Formatting tab

Answer (score 0):

ok. here is code add it to your HTML/Javascript box with this you will see the Navigation box at the end of your blogger blog. (if your blog already have navigation button them leave it)

```
<style type="text/CSS">
.showpageArea a {  text-decoration:underline;  }  .showpageNum a {  text-decoration:none;  border: 1px solid #7AA1C3;  margin:0 3px;  padding:3px;  }  .showpageNum a:hover {  border: 1px solid #7AA1C3;  background-color:#F6F6F6;  }  .showpagePoint {  color:#333;  text-decoration:none;  border: 1px solid #7AA1C3;  background: #F6F6F6;  margin:0 3px;  padding:3px;  }  .showpageOf {  text-decoration:none;  padding:3px;  margin: 0 3px 0 0;  }  .showpage a {  text-decoration:none;  border: 1px solid #7AA1C3;  padding:3px;  }  .showpage a:hover {  text-decoration:none;  }  .showpageNum a:link,.showpage a:link {  text-decoration:none;  color:#7AA1C3;  }  </style>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function showpageCount(json) {  var thisUrl = location.href;  var htmlMap = new Array();  var isFirstPage = 

thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.length-5,thisUrl.length)==".com/";  var isLablePage = thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/")!=-1;  var isPage = thisUrl.indexOf("/search?updated")!=-1;  var thisLable = isLablePage ? thisUrl.substr(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/")+14,thisUrl.length) : "";  thisLable = thisLable.indexOf("?")!=-1 ? thisLable.substr(0,thisLable.indexOf("?")) : thisLable;  var thisNum = 1;  var postNum=1;  var itemCount = 0;  var fFlag = 0;  var eFlag = 0;  var html= '';  var upPageHtml ='';  var downPageHtml ='';
var pageCount = 2;  var displayPageNum = 5;  var upPageWord = 'Previous';  var downPageWord = 'Next';

var labelHtml = '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="/search/label/'+thisLable+'?&max-results='+pageCount+'">';
for(var i=0, post; post = json.feed.entry[i]; i++) {  var timestamp = post.published.$t.substr(0,10);  var title = post.title.$t;  if(isLablePage){  if(title!=''){  if(post.category){  for(var c=0, post_category; post_category = post.category[c]; c++) {  if(encodeURIComponent(post_category.term)==thisLable){  if(itemCount==0 || (itemCount % pageCount ==(pageCount-1))){  if(thisUrl.indexOf(timestamp)!=-1 ){  thisNum = postNum;  }
postNum++;  htmlMap[htmlMap.length] = '/search/label/'+thisLable+'?updated-max='+timestamp+'T00%3A00%3A00%2B08%3A00&max-results='+pageCount;  }  }  }  }//end if(post.category){
itemCount++;  }
}else{  if(title!=''){  if(itemCount==0 || (itemCount % pageCount ==(pageCount-1))){  if(thisUrl.indexOf(timestamp)!=-1 ){  thisNum = postNum;  }
if(title!='') postNum++;  htmlMap[htmlMap.length] = '/search?updated-max='+timestamp+'T00%3A00%3A00%2B08%3A00&max-results='+pageCount;  }  }  itemCount++;  }  }
for(var p =0;p< htmlMap.length;p++){  if(p>=(thisNum-displayPageNum-1) && p<(thisNum+displayPageNum)){  if(fFlag ==0 && p == thisNum-2){  if(thisNum==2){  if(isLablePage){  upPageHtml = labelHtml + upPageWord +'</a></span>';  }else{  upPageHtml = '<span class="showpage"><a href="/">'+ upPageWord +'</a></span>';  }  }else{  upPageHtml = '<span class="showpage"><a href="'+htmlMap[p]+'">'+ upPageWord +'</a></span>';  }
fFlag++;  }
if(p==(thisNum-1)){  html += '<span class="showpagePoint">'+thisNum+'</span>';  }else{  if(p==0){  if(isLablePage){  html = labelHtml+'1</a></span>';  }else{  html += '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="/">1</a></span>';  }  }else{  html += '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="'+htmlMap[p]+'">'+ (p+1) +'</a></span>';  }  }
if(eFlag ==0 && p == thisNum){  downPageHtml = '<span class="showpage"> <a href="'+htmlMap[p]+'">'+ downPageWord +'</a></span>';  eFlag++;  }  }//end if(p>=(thisNum-displayPageNum-1) && p<(thisNum+displayPageNum)){  }//end for(var p =0;p< htmlMap.length;p++){
if(thisNum>1){  if(!isLablePage){  html = ''+upPageHtml+' '+html +' ';  }else{  html = ''+upPageHtml+' '+html +' ';  }  }
html = '<div class="showpageArea"><span style="COLOR: #000;" class="showpageOf"> Pages ('+(postNum-1)+')</span>'+html;
if(thisNum<(postNum-1)){  html += downPageHtml;
}
if(postNum==1) postNum++;  html += '</div>';
if(isPage || isFirstPage || isLablePage){  var pageArea = document.getElementsByName("pageArea");  var blogPager = document.getElementById("blog-pager");
if(postNum <= 2){  html ='';  }
for(var p =0;p< pageArea.length;p++){  pageArea[p].innerHTML = html;  }
if(pageArea&&pageArea.length>0){  html ='';  }
if(blogPager){  blogPager.innerHTML = html;  }  }
}  </script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=showpageCount&max-results=99999" ; type="text/javascript"></script><a href="http://letdld.blogspot.com/2013/03/fast-free-social-widget-for-blogger.html">Social share widget</a></h6>
```

Now click on next to show new pages, Now see the address bar where you look this text in url **max-results=5** change it to how much you need post on one page

Or simply edit the code

```
thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.length-5
var pageCount = 2;  var displayPageNum = 5
```

Change **5** and **2** to how much you need to show post.

It works on me. Try that

Comment: He didn't ask for how to edit a blog, he asked for how to bypass a blogger's settings and force the site to list more posts at a time.